# What happened to the group at Grady Memorial Hospital?

Tags: the-walking-dead

He everyone,

I'm rewatching season 5 of The Walking Dead and I just saw the scene when Beth got killed and the police officers behind Dawn tell them to leave and that they'll never see them again.

Are they still alive 10 years later or did they get overrun?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Gregory Nicotero an special effects creator, actor and director on the show stated during a Live  Q&A (hosted by Shindig.com on May 29, 2020) that they are all dead. No reason was given to how or why they died but seeing they are all confirmed dead it's logical to assume they got overrun.

Comment: Or succumbed to the fever